# Will not update my xml doc

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms, linq

Need to be able to change and element from True to False

```
    For Each item In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        Dim appQuery = _
            From c In doc.<applications>.<app> _
            Where c.<appName>.Value = item _
            Select c.<appName>, c.<appfav>
        For Each result In appQuery
            result.appfav.Value = False
        Next
    Next

doc.Save(xmlFilePath)
```

What am I not seeing?

Comment: Have you tried `result.appfav.Value = "False"`?

Comment: It looks as though 'result' is an object with two properties, appName and appFav. I'd assume you'd just set it via result.appfav = false

Comment: I have tried "False", but i am storing that value as a boolean, so I've tried both ways. I am storing both properties as I am also using appNam but didn't add the code as its not an issue.

Comment: I am open to a different block of code. I don't see why this one will not change the value. I used the same code block to CNG another value to += 1 and it works fine. Am I not referring to the value correctly because its a boolean value or... I tried to messagebox.show(result.appFav.value) and it returns an empty message box. I am clearly missing something..

Answer (score 0):

So,

I added an item to the select statement and everything works. I remove it, and it doesn't I am baffled, but operational.

```
   For Each item In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        Dim appQuery = _
            From c In doc.<applications>.<app> _
            Where c.<appName>.Value = item _
            Select c.<appName>, c.<appfav>, c.<appType>
        For Each result In appQuery
            result.appfav.Value = False
        Next
    Next

doc.Save(xmlFilePath)
```